# Attempt to perform arithmetic on global 't1' (a table value)

Tags: lua

Trying to add tables, using metatables, I get this error, I have really complicated here and there is no way to solve (I am learning Lua)
)

```
mt = { ___add = function (a,b)
                local s = {}
                for k,v in ipairs( a ) do s[#s + 1] = v end
                for k,v in ipairs( b ) do s[#s + 1] = v end
               end
    }

t1 = {1,2,3}
t2 = {4,5}
setmetatable( t1, mt )
print(table.concat(t1+t2, ", "))
```

It gives me this result when trying to "compile" with the interpreter

```
main.lua:15: attempt to perform arithmetic on global 't1' (a table value)
main.lua:15: in main chunk
```

Comment: It should be noted, that I am using Lua 5.1 in Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems in your code:

- The name of the metamethod is `__add`, with *two* underscores, not  *three*.
- You need to return `s` in the metamethod.

After you fix these, the code works as expected.

Comment: Yes, those were the problems, fix the underscore and add the 's' return.

Thanks